# c++ extract numbers from a string separated by symbols

Tags: c++

I have a problem here, I want to split a string of numbers and "+-/*" symbols but I'm stuck here,

here's my try

```
stringstream test("13-2+14-15*12");
string segment;
while(getline(test, segment, '-') || getline(test, segment, '+') || getline(test, segment, '/') || getline(test, segment, '*'))
{
    cout << segment << endl;
   numbers.push(segment);
}
```

but output is "15*12 2+14 13" not "15 12 2 14 13".
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After the first number, alternate using `>>` to extract a `char` (your operator) and an `int` (your argument).

Comment: What is `numbers`?

Comment: `getline(test, segment, '-')` will always be true if there is any data in the stream left to read. Since `||` short circuits the rest won't ever be evaluated until there is an error and they will all fail.

Comment: See [C++ Extracting the integer in a string with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820639/c-extracting-the-integer-in-a-string-with-multiple-delimiters) and [Extracting Numbers from Mixed String using stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066457/extracting-numbers-from-mixed-string-using-stringstream)

Comment: You can do this in one line:  `std::replace_if(str.begin(),str.end(),::ispunct,' ');`

Comment: quite a hasty closure IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a splitting approach with the regex `[*/+-]`:

```cpp
std::string str = "13-2+14-15*12";
std::regex rgx("[*/+-]");
std::sregex_token_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), rgx, -1);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter)
    std::cout << *iter << '\n';
```